# Add link to image attachment in Jira description/comment without displaying thumbnail

Tags: jira

I'm using Jira server (on-premises hosted, not cloud). When I click the attachment button in the Description field or a comment to add a link to an image that was attached to the issue previously, it is displaying a thumbnail of the attachment, which totally throws off the formatting of the Description/comment. Is there any way to suppress this behavior so it just displays a link to the image that expands to a modal, similar to the experience when you click on the attachment name in the list of attachments?

Answer (score 0):

I found, in our jira configuration, that the thumbnail (thumbnails) inserts itself (insert themselves) before the start of the existing text in the comment, shunting the text towards the right. So I just inserted a carriage return before the start of the shunted text. Then I still had large icons at the start of the comment, but the text formatting was fine because it started on a new line again, after the icons.

Comment: This was because I entered the text of the comment first, saved it, then added the attachment as a separate edit stage. This causes the edit cursor to position itself at the beginning of the text. Whereas if I added the attachments after the entering the text in a single edit operation, then I saw the problem described by the o.p.